# Render text output on button click

Tags: r, shiny

I want to update the value of a text output on a button click. I am not very familiar with shiny, but I would have assumed that it would be a straight forward thing to do..

I have an observeEvent that listens to a button click. I want to update the text output to the value of my selectInput on click. How can I achieve this, see the # **** in my code for the specific code that should update the text output, it is not working

```
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- htmlTemplate("template.html",
    run = actionButton("run", "Run"),
    
    # **** The text output
    levelName = textOutput("level"),

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$listLevelNames <- renderUI({
        selectInput("selectLevelName", "Select level name",
            choices = c("Class", "Order", "Suborder", "Alliance", "Assoc"),
            selected = "Class"
        )
    })

    output$listLevelValues <- renderUI({
        selectInput("selectLevelValue", "Select level value",
            choices = c("A","B","C"),
            selected = "A"
        )
    })
    

  
    runOutput <- observeEvent(input$run, {
        level.name <- input$selectLevelName
        level.value <- input$selectLevelValue
        
        # **** set text output value
        output$level <- renderText(level.name)

        level_name_dir <- file.path("level", level.name)
        if (!dir.exists(level_name_dir)) dir.create(level_name_dir, recursive = TRUE)

        level_value_dir <- file.path(level_name_dir, level.value)
        if (!dir.exists(level_value_dir)) dir.create(level_value_dir, recursive = TRUE)

        script <- file.path(level_value_dir, "_targets.R")

        write_pipeline(level_value_dir, level.name, level.value)
        tar_make(
            script = script
        )
        setwd(wd)
        generateReport(level.name, level.value)
    })
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**template.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    {{ headContent() }}
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://bootswatch.com/united/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <img class="bc-logo" src="bc-logo.svg" alt="logo" />
        </div>
        <div
          class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right flex-container"
          style="margin-right: 100px"
        >
          <div id="listLevelNames" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
          <div id="listLevelValues" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
          <div style="margin-top: 25px">{{ run }}</div>
          {{levelName}}

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: @YBS yes, but I can still access it in my template.html file and it works fine. In my template.html file I do    <div id="listLevelNames" class="shiny-html-output"></div> <div id="listLevelValues" class="shiny-html-output"></div> and it works fine

Comment: Sorry, I cannot test the code without `template.html` and `hier`

Comment: @YBS I have added the template.html file now, thanks

Comment: And I have removed hier

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to test it, as I get `Error in list2env(vars, parent = globalenv()) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name`

Comment: Thanks for trying, there is ibiousky something going on there with my code. Nevertheless, how would you do it groom scratch? Just a simple example would help and be sufficient for an answer

Comment: Simply add a reference to the button in your `renderText`. And never, ever, nest reactives. For example, the fact that your `renderText` is inside your `observeEvent` is a recipe for disaster.